# Is there a Hebrew Calendar backdated to 500 B.C. or earlier, in an importable format like CSV or JSON?

Tags: calendar

I'm putting together a program that will allow many different calendars to be correlated via Julian Day so that world events, personal notes, or even scriptural passages can be associated with multiple calendars simultaneously.

Does anyone know of a Hebrew calendar which has been backdated to 500 B.C. or earlier? It would be helpful if it's in a format such as Tab Delimited, CSV, JSON or some other machine-readable format. However, at this point anything would be most appreciated!

Comment: You can program a calendar yourself in an hour https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/128332/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you very much! If I can't find one already created, this gives me a great starting point!

Comment: It would be a "virtual" Hebrew date, in that the fixed calendar we have now was not in operation then (not till c400 CE I think) so the date then would likely be different

Comment: @AKA Correct. I'm trying to create a "virtual" calendar of most current calendars to allow for continuity across time. If there is more information on the calendar used pre Hillel II, I'd be interested in researching that as well. To my current knowledge, such a calendar is not known.

Comment: @RAB there was *no* calendar really - months were declared based on witnessing the New Moon, and leap-months were probably not fully predictable

Comment: To add to AKA's point, there were general guidelines, but the High Court had a certain amount of leeway in determining the calendar, and not all the considerations were astronomical.

Comment: @N.T. May I ask if this is based on an absence of historical evidence, or if there is some historical evidence indicating that's how it ran? I'm not trying to be contentious, I've just never found anything showing the calendar in use pre-Babylon. I have found copious documentation about the Babylonian calendar, which is similar to what you described.

Comment: It's discussed at length in tractate Rosh Hashana and Maimonides' laws of Kiddush Hachodesh.