# Program to find likelihood of potential calendrical occurrences

Tags: calendar

Someone asked me over kiddush about the frequency of the following scenario:

```
Shabbat Rosh Chodesh
In a leap year
On Adar II
```

In such a case, R"CH would also be Shekalim, so that might be faster to extrapolate.

Rather than asking for this specific case, is there a program which I could use to find the frequency of a particular occurrence in our calendar ?

Comment: What level precision are you looking for? Consider https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/136459/759 and a leap year is 7/19 so your answer is approximately 1/19 years