Rarest calendar year
There are many variables in a jewish calendar year, so for the purpose of my question, I'm asking for the rarest confluence of "days of the week" with significant calendar dates (to determine what significant means, let's say days that we don't say tachanun).
So for example, for Rosh Hashana to occur on a monday, Hannukah on a Shabbat, Tu B'shvat to occur on a Wednesday, Purim on a Thursday... and so on may be the rarest combination.
(If I'm not mistaken, this question should be Israel/Diaspora agnostic.)
Bonus question: when did this year last occur and when will it occur next?

Yom Ha'atzmut is up to the responder to decide ;)

355-day year starting on Thursday

Jewish calendar has 19 year moon cycle and 28 year solar cycle when everything comes to the same day of the week. 19 and 28 are relatively prime, so every 532 =19×28 years we should get a repetition. I.e. had the calendar been infinite - everything might average out. We believe that the calendar is 6000 years. Thus definitely it makes sense to ask, which occurence is the rarest and actually compute it!

@DoubleAA which we will have this coming year (5785)

@YDJ That's not how it works. The calendar almost repeats every 247 years, but the actual length of the cycle is 689,472 years. https://hebrewcalendar.tripod.com/#19

@JoelK that's why Jewish calendar is unfalsifiable. I.e. one cannot skip few years and get the same date difference. Solar calendars are all falsifiable.

@YDJ As per Rambam, Hil. Kiddush Hachodesh, there's nothing Jewish in the "Jewish Calendar".

@YDJ I remind you that before fixing the calendar by Hillel II in the 4th century, Rosh Chodesh and hence festivals could move according to Beis Din's decisions. Similarly, Ibur Hashana depended on the Nasi's decision that was aligned with the Romans

@AlBerko not sure. First mitzvah in Mitzrayim was to count months. It maybe the case to some degree. The Babylonian calendar supposedly from Adam haRishon was very similar to Jewish calendar,  except they would double either Adar or Elul in a leap year based on some calculations.

As noted by DoubleAA in a comment, the rarest of the 14 possible types of year in the Hebrew calendar, is a 355-day year (i.e. a regular 12-month year, with both Marcheshvan and Kislev having 30 days) starting with Rosh HaShanah on a Thursday.
This year-type can be referred to as הש"א (that is ה - Rosh HaShanah is Thursday, ש (=שלמה) - Marcheshvan and Kislev have 30 days, א - first day Pesach is Sunday).
Some key facts, all taken from the relevant (Hebrew) Wikipedia page:

Last happened in 5754 (1993-94)
Next happens in 5785 (2024-25)
After that it happens in 5805 (2044-45)
In the long-run, this type only occurs in 3.3% of all years

Some calendrical quirks of this year-type (not all of them unique to this year-type alone):

Asarah B'Tevet falls on a Friday - the only fast that is widely observed on a Friday
The regular haftarah for Parshat Mishpatim is read - this is the only type of 12-month year in which this happens
Vayakhel and Pekudei are read on separate shabbatot - this is the only type of 12-month year in which this happens
Purim falls on a Friday (and in walled cities on shabbat - known as purim meshulash)
Erev Pesach falls on shabbat


This is all correct, and while some people do get excited about Vayaqhel/Pekudei being separate not in a leap year, for most people they just care about the main holiday stretch from Purim to Simchas Torah where there are really just four options with rather predictable distributions and a clear "rarest" version as described here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/136460/759
