2 Rosh Hashonos on Tuesday in a row
I have been making tables to better understand the Hebrew calendar. Here is a picture:

מלא = מ,
כסדרן = כ,
חסר = ח,
שנה פשוטה = פ,
שנה מעוברת = ע
The numbers represent the days of the week upon which Rosh Chodesh falls.
I initially used all possible iterations, and then deleted those that caused the following Rosh Hashono to fall on Sunday, Wednesday, and Friday.
I checked Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Days_of_week_on_Hebrew_calendar) to see if this was correct, and discovered there cannot be two Rosh Hashonos in a row that fall on Tuesdays, despite this being theoretically possible in a leap year in which both Cheshvon and Kisleiv have 30 days (מ״ע).
Therefore, my question is: Why can there not be two consecutive Rosh Hashonos that fall on Tuesday?

Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75796/759

During the thirteen months of a leap year, there are 54 weeks 5 days 21 hours 589 chalakim from the molad of Tishri at the start of the year to the molad of Tishri at the start of the next year.
Ignoring full weeks, the molad therefore shifts by 5 days 21 hours 589 chalakim from the beginning to the end of the leap year.
For a leap year to start on a Tuesday, the molad at the start of the year must fall between 6pm Monday and 6pm Tuesday. Any earlier means that Rosh HaShanah is Monday; any later and it’s Thursday.
But this means that the following year the molad must fall between Sunday 3pm and 529 chalakim and Monday 3pm and 529 chalakim. So the following year’s Rosh HaShanah must fall on Monday.

Source for the number https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23306/759

The same sort of calculation follows in a non-leap year (2/15/589-3/9/4 goes to 7/0/385-7/18/00) whereby the next RH is always on Shabbat. This leads to two convenient calendar corollaries: Years starting on Tuesday are always Kisidran, and therefore Chanuka (which starts on the same day as RH when Marcheshvan has 30 days, or else the day before) can't start on a Tuesday.

And a corollary of the corollary: the 5th night of chanukah can never fall on Fri night, which is cited as the reason for the custom that some have to specifically give chanukah gelt on that night.
